# Lightweight boilerplate alternatives for mobile web site

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, boilerplate, html5boilerplate

What is a good lightweight mobile website boilerplate solution for building mobile websites? I'm building a mobile website and would like to find a good solution that I can use again for future projects.

I've found a few:

- JQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/)
- HTML5 Boilerplate Mobile (http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile)
- Skeleton (http://www.getskeleton.com/)

Although it seems like JQuery Mobile is favored, it does seem like a huge payload to deliver to every mobile user. HTML5  Boilerplate Mobile looks like a nice alternative, as I've used HTML5BP for past projects.

Skeleton seems to be the most lightweight solution, but I'm concerned about its possible lack of support in the future. I don't know enough about it, maybe someone could shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

Stick with jQuery Mobile and you are incorrect to assume it has a huge "payload". It is implemented using Unobtrusive JavaScript. Source markup is extremely light and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself what exactly it is that are you looking for :

- Are you looking for a CSS framework with no JS, with some JS or a full CSS/JS hybrid framework?
- Are you looking for a framework that supports both desktop and mobile or something exclusively focused on mobile?

Some options to consider, depending on what you're looking for :

- [**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [**Zurb Foundation**](http://foundation.zurb.com/) are the two most popular options of CSS frameworks and both some with some JS and work great with modern browsers, but might be lacking if you still need to support IE8-.
- If you don't need JS features and want to have a footprint as light as possible while still supporting IE6+, you could try my own [**Cascade Framework Light**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframeworklight/) (which is only 2Kb).
- If you want a CSS only framework focused exclusively on mobile, you could try something like [**Clank**](http://getclank.com/).
- If you are looking for a full hybrid CSS/JS framework, you might want to look into something like [**Ionic**](http://ionicframework.com/) or [**Mobile Angular UI**](http://mobileangularui.com/).

Each of these frameworks is so very different in architecture and focus. Whichever of them (or whichever of the many others that I haven't mentioned here) works best for you really depends on your needs.